# Should a certificate be installed when a browser offers to install it?

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, internet

I was accessing my internet banking site, and I found my browser asking to install some certificates noted some extensions of certificate.

Do I need to install certificate to access the site safely or can I access it ignoring the suggestion of installing certificate?

Do certificates help more in secure browsing?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your bank wants to establish a secure connection to you. To make sure that the connection is secure, a set of certificates must be installed on both your client and the bank's servers. If the website that you blurred out is correct, then installing the certificates is perfectly safe.

TL;DR: **press Install to access your bank securely.**

Comment: I'd still first ask the bank what's going on. While using certificates is a good thing to do, if the site OP wanted to reach doesn't use them normally, someone might have tinkered with DNS and that URL doesn't point to where it should. I have not yet encountered any site using personal certificates, so I'd be sceptical. Never hurts to ask first.

Comment: @Izzy would you please tell how much is the possibility that this can be tinkered and mislead us from making secure connections to the bank.

Comment: @Lukas that might be a question for Security.SE. I just know the possibility exists. If you want to dig in a bit, one variant is called "cache poisoning" (causing your legit DNS to resolve to wrong addresses). Another possibility is a "wrong link" e.g. via a phishing mail. There are more possibilities, but that's going to far here (and I'm not really the expert in this area).